# Magento 2 extends ProductsList Widget

Tags: magento2, widget

I am trying to extend Magento 2's core ProductsList widget, but getting following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to VendorName\ModuleName\Block\ProductsList\Interceptor::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context, instance of Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory given, called in D:\xampp\htdocs\magento226\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php on line 111 and defined in D:\xampp\htdocs\magento226\generated\code\VendorName\ModuleName\Block\ProductsList\Interceptor.php:11 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento226\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(111): VendorName\ModuleName\Block\ProductsList\Interceptor->__construct(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory)) #1 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento226\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('VendorName\\ModuleName\\B...', Array) #2 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento226\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(56): Mage in D:\xampp\htdocs\magento226\generated\code\VendorName\ModuleName\Block\ProductsList\Interceptor.php on line 11
```

Below is my custom ProductsList class code

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Block;

use \Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList as MagentoProductsList;
use \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory as CategoryCollectionFactory;

class ProductsList extends MagentoProductsList {

    protected $_categoryCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
           CategoryCollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory)
    {
        $this->_categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
    }


    public function test() {
        //other code here
    }
```

Please tell me how I can use categoryCollectionFactory like I did in my other custom modules, or am I missing something basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following way:

```
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Block;

use \Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList as MagentoProductsList;
use \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory as CategoryCollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;

class ProductsList extends MagentoProductsList
{
    protected $_categoryCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $catalogProductVisibility,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
        \Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\Sql\Builder $sqlBuilder,
        \Magento\CatalogWidget\Model\Rule $rule,
        \Magento\Widget\Helper\Conditions $conditionsHelper,
        CategoryCollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,
        array $data = [],
        Json $json = null
    ) {
        $this->_categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $productCollectionFactory,
            $catalogProductVisibility,
            $httpContext,
            $sqlBuilder,
            $rule,
            $conditionsHelper,
            $data,
            $json
        );
    }
}
```

Remove **generated/***